# Pycharm Error with creating Django project with remote vagrant interpreter

Tags: python, django, pycharm, remote-access, interpreter

I have a problem while I am creating the  Django project with remote vagrant interpreter.

All the steps went successful and I am able to see the vagrant interpreter but cannot create the project because of this error "Please choose a local interpreter".

1- I have installed the Pip on remote vagrant box

2- I have installed the Django on the remote vagrant box

[image]

Comment: I have gotten the answer of jetbrains support team: "It's the known issue, please, vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14036 to increase its priority and be notified about updates."

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's the reason, but creation of project with local interpreter and later update it in settings worked for me.